# Can you crit with the minus 5 from sharpshooter?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, critical-hit

I'm pretty new to the game and can't find this question answered anywhere. I'm looking at the feat sharpshooter and I saw that you can take a -5 to the attack roll for a +10 damage. I'm curious if you can still crit if you roll a natural 20 after you've chosen to take the -5 hit to the attack roll.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Yes, if you roll a natural 20, it will be a critical hit despite your -5 penalty.

> If the d20 roll for an attack is a 20, the attack
>   hits **regardless of any modifiers** or the target’s AC.
>   This is called a critical hit, which is explained later
>   in this chapter.

Answer (score 11):

When you roll a 20 on an attack, it is always considered a critical and successful hit.

So yes, whatever the penalty you might have, it works.

Actually, if you do 15 + 5, it is not a critical hit. It has to be a natural 20. (Although there are some class abilities that allow a natural 19 to be a critical hit as well, such as the Champion Fighter Archetypes, PHB p. 72, it's still the natural roll that matters.)

Comment: @Miniman Perhaps the last fragment of the sentence. I know that certain weapons have increased crit ranges. I'm almost certain that sneak attacks don't affect crit range, though.

Comment: @Miniman I am! Thank you! I totally forgot that they removed crit range because they also removed threat/confirm!

Comment: @KorvinStarmast, sorry, yes indeed,,, I was mixing up critical hit and advantage on the Rogue. I added a reference with the page number.

Comment: @AlexisWilke Improved the answer, previous comment removed.