# Do you multiply the bonus damage from taking a -5 on attacks using the Sharpshooter feat?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, ranged-attack

Inspired by [Can you crit with the minus 5 from sharpshooter?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/72220/can-you-crit-with-the-minus-5-from-sharpshooter).

It was asked if you could still crit with Sharpshooter's -5 to hit / +10 to damage option active, but that got me wondering -- do you multiply that bonus damage, should you crit on your attack?  At an additional 10-20 points, that could be a massive increase in damage.

Answer (score 25):

No. Only damage *dice* are doubled - static modifiers like the +10 from Sharpshooter are unaffected by a critical hit.

> When you score a critical hit, you get to roll extra dice
>   for the attack’s damage against the target. Roll all of the
>   attack’s damage dice twice and add them together. **Then
>   add any relevant modifiers as normal.** To speed up play,
>   you can roll all the damage dice at once.

(PHB p.196, emphasis mine)